# Hibernate Search: background helper for indexing

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

We are planning to use Hibernate Search with Lucene in a project, which eventually has to replace a currently running application. Hibernate search itself works quite well, but I have some questions about the indexing. We have a lot of legacy data in our database, a database worker changing and adding data in the background and also the old application which is planned to be running in parallel with the new application for some time. If it was only about the legacy data, I could run the indexing once at the first start of the program, but to also get the changes performed by the old application and the database worker I would need to have a background helper to update the index on a regular basis. Is there a way to accomplish this with a satisfying performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a similar situation myself, and our solution was to schedule a nightly job which would run the index rebuild.

I had to spend some time making sure the rebuild process would be fast enough, this might need a bit of research and enabling Hibernate's 2nd level cache on some hot entities and critical relations.

Of course this approach is only valid if your application can tolerate working on a slightly out of sync index until night fall.

Other people have been using the master/slave configuration over JMS, so that one single node (the master) would rebuild indexes more often than once a day: you can specify which entities need to have the index rebuilt so you might be able to limit such actions on crucial tables, or only those actually touched by the legacy apps.

Typically such a "master" node will only rebuild indexes and serve index refreshes to the slaves, while web requests would be served by the slaves, so that the overhead on the master can be throttled without having an impact on webserver performance. Don't forget to tune the parallelism and the connection pools on the master node as well so that it doesn't put too much load on your database: in this case rather than tuning it to finish as soon as possible, you'll prefer it to work slower.